# Databricks (SQL)

Tags: sql, databricks

Need help with Databricks SQL code.

The company uses Oracle-Toad for SQL queries and the person that ran the queries left the company. I work with Python but tasked with the SQL processes. Company recently switched to Databricks for SQL and when I run the two queries that ran in Oracle, it gives several errors in Databricks.

Error:
[DATATYPE_MISMATCH.UNEXPECTED_INPUT_TYPE] Cannot resolve "1 + (End_Date - Start_Date)" due to data type mismatch: Parameter 1 requires the "(TIMESTAMP OR TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE)" type, however "1" has the type "INT".; line 11, pos 13

The SQL code exceeds the maximum 30000 characters so attached an image of the code.

Thanks!

[image: SQL code] Paste in browser

Answer (score 1):

`(End_Date - Start_Date)` does not return an INT data type, so you cannot add 1 to it.

Try replacing `(End_Date - Start_Date)` with `DATEDIFF(DAYS, Start_Date, End_Date)`

Comment: Added your comments to the code and received the following:         [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `DAYS` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`Day_Amt`, `RunDate`, `End_Date`, `Member_ID`, `Start_Date`].; line 11, pos 66

Comment: Okay so maybe it's different in Oracle SQL, try `TO_DATE(End_Date, 'YYYYMMDD') -  
       TO_DATE(Start_Date, 'YYYYMMDD')`